# What does *** CPSZ: mean in Cabal build log when building Idris?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, idris

I'm currently building Idris via `cabal install idris`. In response to the output:

```
Redirecting build log to {handle:/home/me/.cabal/logs/idris-0.9.14.3.log}
```

I decided to track the build with `tail -f /home/me/.cabal/logs/idris-0.9.14.3.log`.

While much of the output is meaningful, along the lines of:

```
Simplifier:
Result size of Simplifier iteration=1
  = {terms: 77,520, types: 104,583, coercions: 37,209}
Result size of Simplifier iteration=2
  = {terms: 59,582, types: 78,325, coercions: 18,371}
```

There are many lines that only contain

`*** CPSZ:`

So I was wondering, purely out of curiosity, what "`*** CPSZ:`" represents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like these duplicated lines were caused by a [bug in GHC](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8973). As to what CPSZ stands for, it appears to mean ["continuation passing style zipper"](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/176fa33f17dd78355cc572e006d2ab26898e2c69:/compiler/cmm/CmmCPSZ.hs). The CPSZ pass (which was since either removed or renamed) performed [CPS-conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) on Cmm code. Cmm is one of GHC's internal representation languages. The "zipper" part comes from Cmm [control flow graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) [being represented](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/zipcfg-abstract.html) as a [zipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_%28data_structure%29) internally.